# Como habilitar o Netbeans para abrir uma pasta no sistema(Open in system browser)?

Tags: netbeans, plugin, ide

Eu abria todos os meu projetos direto pelo `netbeans`, mas precisei remover o netbeans do computador e todas as minhas configurações foram perdidas, realmente não lembro como fiz isso usando os `plugins` na aba de ferramentas.
Antes eu simplesmente abria a opção arquivo do menu da IDE e la estava `Open in system browser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize este plugin **[QuickOpener](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/43217/quickopener)**, testado e funcionando!

Referência: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2624485/1997073

Comment: Celso Marigo Jr Parece que também é possível fazer o mesmo com outros plugins!!

Comment: @CelsoMagiro Muito bom o QuickOpener. Muito obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 1):

**Finalmente consegui insatlar o plugin (Open Containing Folder)** depois de instalado você clica com o botão sobre o projeto e na lista de opções que aparece é  possível escolher `Open in system browser`

Menu -> Ferramentas (Alt-T) -> Plugins (G). 
Selecione "`Plug-ins Disponíveis`" 
Digite "`Open Containing Folder`" no box de pesquisa
Selecione `Open Containing Folder` na lista
Click  no botão `Instalar` 
 
Click  no botão `Próximo`
Marque o check-box "`Eu aceito os termos em todos os contratos de licença.`" 
Click no botão `Instalar!`
A `IDE` vai perguntar se você quer reiniciar para usar o `Plugin`
Escolha reiniciar.
Está feito!